# Tooltip customization in C3js

Tags: d3.js, c3.js, stacked-chart

Here is a stacked bar chart example created using C3js library

http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html

Want to modify tooltip.

currently there are two columns in tooltip .**want to show one additional column in tooltip.**  so there will be tree columns data

Comment: you can use this to customize your tooltip http://c3js.org/reference.html#tooltip-contents

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things, depending on your real need
1. (my preffered) Using [tooltip-contents](http://c3js.org/reference.html#tooltip-contents)
In this case you have the full power of designing the tooltip the way you need
with inline annonymous function

**d argument is the data array with all data points for this exact position on chart**
Example:

```
tooltip: {
  contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
    return ... // formatted html as you want
  }
}
```

2. You can create a custom CSS and bind it to "c3-tooltip-container" class elements.

"c3-tooltip-name--%myseriesname%" for example is one TR class for the series name etc, so if the column is static you can create a :before/:after pseudo CSS class and add something there.

3. you can use D3 to find the tooltip element by it's class ("c3-tooltip") in order to add a column
   Something like: d3.select("c3-tooltip").append( your column here )

**but you will have to run this .onrender which will make it slower**